# Warnings about missing Permissions attribute when loading javafx application

Tags: java, javafx

My javafx application gives warnings when it loads with Java7u25

Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: XXX.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: XXX.jar

My jnlp does not have Codebase attribute defined and Permissions are set to all-permissions.

I specified Permissions attribute in the JAR's manifest according to jnlp. Did the same on third party jars as well.

Now warnings do not appear on console. But still application does not load.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, and found the url below. Hope this is helpful.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/no_redeploy.html